# ServiceHost AddServiceEndpoint - multiple connections

Tags: c#, wcf, network-programming, duplex-channel

I have a Duplex WFC client based on [this](http://realfiction.net/go/113) which, when used with a single client works fine. The problem arises when I try to connect more than one client to the server. When I do, I get an exception: `There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:9080/MyDataService/1617f081e4b04c288965eea6ae18a39f that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.`

I define my endpoint like this:

```
ServiceHost duplex = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerWCallbackImpl));
```

and add my client endpoint like this:

```
duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServerWithCallback), new NetTcpBinding(), uniqueEndpointAddress);
```

There is no problem with the first connection but when I attempt to connect with a second client in the same way, the above exception is thrown.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in Adv!

Comment: Does it throw immediately or does it wait a few seconds? (Where a few seconds == whatever your client timeout is set to)

Comment: It seems as though the ServiceHost will accept only one Endpoint.

Comment: You can try to turn up concurrency in the service host, but I wouldn't expect it to throw immediately if it were the normal service host concurrency knobs.
Unfortunately WCF hasn't made this easy for you, with concurrency knobs in a bunch of places. A search for ServiceThrottlingBehavior should help.

Comment: So you are running multiple clients on the same machine? Do you have Net.Tcp port sharing service running?

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, that helped! I never knew that setting was even there. However, I find that if I have a channel already streaming data  when I add another, the second seems to cancel out the data from the 1st subscription. Any ideas what might cause this?